# Databricks Pyspark - Group related rows

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I am parsing an EDI file in Azure Databricks. Rows in the input file are related to other rows based on the order in which they appear. What I need is a way to group related rows together.

```
import pyspark.sql.types as T
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

data = [
    ('book000book title',),
    ('auth001first author',),
    ('auth002second author',),
    ('book003another book',),
    ('auth004third author',),
]

schema = T.StructType([T.StructField('Line', T.StringType())])
books = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

books = (books
        .withColumn('RecordType', F.substring(F.col('Line'), 1, 4))
        .withColumn('Sequence', F.substring(F.col('Line'), 5, 3))
        .withColumn('Title', F.when(F.col('RecordType') == 'book', F.trim(F.substring(F.col('Line'), 8, 20))).otherwise(F.lit(None)))
        .withColumn('Author', F.when(F.col('RecordType') == 'auth', F.trim(F.substring(F.col('Line'), 8, 20))).otherwise(F.lit(None)))
        .drop('Line')
        )

window = Window.orderBy('Sequence')
books = (books
         .withColumn('BookID', F.row_number().over(window))
        )

books.show()
```

Following a `book` record, the subsequent lines are the authors for that book so those authors should have the same `BookID` as the last `book` record before them.

The output of this is:

```
+----------+--------+------------+-------------+------+
|RecordType|Sequence|       Title|       Author|BookID|
+----------+--------+------------+-------------+------+
|      book|     000|  book title|         null|     1|
|      auth|     001|        null| first author|     2|
|      auth|     002|        null|second author|     3|
|      book|     003|another book|         null|     4|
|      auth|     004|        null| third author|     5|
+----------+--------+------------+-------------+------+
```

I need to way to assign the correct `BookID` for each author so that I will be able to group them. The output I'm looking for is:

```
+----------+--------+------------+-------------+------+
|RecordType|Sequence|       Title|       Author|BookID|
+----------+--------+------------+-------------+------+
|      book|     000|  book title|         null|     1|
|      auth|     001|        null| first author|     1|
|      auth|     002|        null|second author|     1|
|      book|     003|another book|         null|     2|
|      auth|     004|        null| third author|     2|
+----------+--------+------------+-------------+------+
```

I haven't been able to figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional sum aggregation over a window ordered by `sequence` like this:

```
books = (books
         .withColumn('BookID', F.sum(F.when(F.col("RecordType") == "book", 1)).over(window))
         )

books.show()
#+----------+--------+------------+-------------+------+
#|RecordType|Sequence|       Title|       Author|BookID|
#+----------+--------+------------+-------------+------+
#|      book|     000|  book title|         null|     1|
#|      auth|     001|        null| first author|     1|
#|      auth|     002|        null|second author|     1|
#|      book|     003|another book|         null|     2|
#|      auth|     004|        null| third author|     2|
#+----------+--------+------------+-------------+------+
```